# gcsfs is not writing files in the google bucket

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

When mounting and writing files in the google cloud storage using the gcsfs, the gcsfs is creating folders and files but not writing files. Most of the times it shows input/output error. It even occurs even when we copy files from local directory to the mounted gcsfs directory.
gcsfs version 0.15

Comment: Quick question, are you talking about this thing? https://code.google.com/p/gcsfs/

Comment: yes Brandon, that's the one.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is quiet an old topic, I will try to provide an answer especially because of people who might stumble on this in the course of their own work. I have experience using more recent versions of `gcsfs` and it works quiet well. You can find the latest documentation at `https://gcsfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest`. To make it work you need to have the environment variable:

`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY.json`.